# Angular MDB module functionality not available in components

Tags: angular, angularjs-scope, components, mdbootstrap

There's a group called MDB (Material Design for Bootstrap) that has released some libraries for Angular. Good stuff. However, when I move their snippets from the parent level of app.component.html where they work fine to a component, things break. I know I'm probably missing something easy...

1. Follow the directions to create a project using Angular MDB.
2. Add some sample code to `app.component.html`. I used flip cards for example.
3. Run your code using `ng serve`. --It all works and looks good.
4. Create a new component, type `ng g component components/demo`. This creates a component in the standard way with 4 necessary files, `.html`, `.scss`, `.spec.ts`, and `.ts`.
5. Now move the sample code to the demo.html and everything breaks.

It's a scoping issue, right? but since their libraries make a lot of resources available as HTML tags, I don't see an easy way to import the functionality into the demo.ts like you would Material stuff. Any suggestions?

Comment: Show me your code.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code in question is one of their "pay" sections and I shouldn't share it here. But if I showed it to you, it wouldn't really add much to the conversation. For example.. here is a modified snippet of what you get...

Comment: <mdb-panel-flip #flipper>
   <!-- Card front -->
   <div class="frame frame-front">
     <!--Card image-->
     <div class="view overlay pattern" mdbEffect>

Comment: There's no .ts code, just tags that rely on their libraries stored in their /node_modules/ folder. The scope to that folder works at the app.module.html level, but not at the components level. This is a generic architecture question and not specific to the code.

Comment: What do you mean by 'everything breaks'? Are there any errors in the console? Did you add the demo.component to the declarations array in your app.module? You can use MDB components in the same exact way as Angular Material components (differences may apply to individual components but the way the library works is the same).

Comment: "everything breaks" = custom classes no longer being applied. There are no errors, because missing class definitions in HTML don't show up in console as errors (at least not that I have seen), I do have the module listed in the declarations section in the app.module.tx, but not as demo.module, but rather DemoModule, and you are correct that you SHOULD be able to do that like Angular, but it's not working. So, i'm hoping it's something architectural I missed.